# Oracle to SQL NEXT_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE) query syntax

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I'm working on a query that needs to be converted from Oracle to SQL for SSMS. I am stuck at this portion though:

```
WHERE
    (irrelevant to question portion of query)
    AND add_dt BETWEEN NEXT_DAY (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 12, 'Monday')
                   AND NEXT_DAY (TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 6, 'Monday')
```

I understand what this does in Oracle, however, I am struggling with the conversion to T-SQL in SSMS.

I appreciate any help given!

I've tried to research converting `NEXT_DAY` to `GETDATE` and `TRUNC` to `DATETIME` but the `SYSDATE` is what is getting me.

Comment: Isn't Oracle `SYSDATE` the same as SQL Server `GETDATE()`?

Comment: "SQL for SSMS"? SSMS is just an IDE-like environment, it supports what ever instance you're connecting to. The important thing is the RDBMS you are using, not the environment.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, your query is identical to:

```
AND add_dt BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5, 'IW') AND TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1, 'IW')
```

Which can be converted to SQL Server as:

```sql
AND add_dt BETWEEN DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE())), 0)
               AND DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Or, from SQL Server 22:

```sql
AND add_dt BETWEEN DATETRUNC(iso_week, DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()))
               AND DATETRUNC(iso_week, DATEADD(day, +1, GETDATE()))
```

---

However, I'm not sure that you want to have the start and end dates of the range 6 days apart because you will get data from an 8-day period most days of the week but on Saturdays you only get a single day.

If you ware expecting to always get a range of 7 days then what you probably want is, in Oracle:

```
AND add_dt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 5, 'IW')
AND add_dt <  TRUNC(SYSDATE + 2, 'IW')
```

Or SQL Server:

```sql
AND add_dt >= DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATEADD(day, -6, GETDATE())), 0)
AND add_dt <  DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())), 0)
```

Or, SQL Server 2022:

```sql
AND add_dt >= DATETRUNC(iso_week, DATEADD(day, -5, GETDATE()))
AND add_dt <  DATETRUNC(iso_week, DATEADD(day, +2, GETDATE()))
```

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/prSCfLoI)

[SQL Server fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_9xUsHcm)

Comment: For SQL Server 2022 and later, you can use  a combination of `DATETRUNC(iso_week, date_value)` and `DATEADD(day, N, date_value)`. While direct addition and subtraction is allowed on the `DATETIME` type, it is not allowed with the newer `DATE` and `DATETIME2` types, so the more explicit `DATEADD()` is preferred for those types.  `DATE_BUCKET()` may also be useful in some scenarios.

Comment: @TN Updated with your suggestions.